# Windows 7 installation from recover partition, keep Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning

I own a X201s. I want to reinstall the win7/64 partition with the recovery partition, without loosing the linux partition. It seems as I do not have any options on installing windows, I can just click a green checkbox. I need to know, if the recovery destroys the linux installation. Partition table looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 121601 Zylinder, zusammen 1953525168 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Festplattenidentifikation: 0x1d131830

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    16259071     8128512    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        16259072   184031231    83886080    6  FAT16
/dev/sda3       184033278  1953523711   884745217    5  Erweiterte
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       184033280   184443436      205078+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6       184444928  1953523711   884539392   83  Linux
```

Has anyone done this before? I just need to know, if the whole partitions are destroyed or if windows is just installed on partition 1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I made a backup and just tried it out, works fine. Windows was installed on sda2, after I formatted the partition with fat32 (error 1 before). The files were written on this partition and didn't even overwrite grub. :-)